# Odoo PoS get orderline product

Tags: javascript, python, odoo, product, point-of-sale

I'm updating the **update_payment_summary** function in the Point_Of_Sale, this function is part of the **PaymentScreenWidget**. 
Now I'd like to retrieve the products from the orderlines.

I tried with

```
var order = this.pos.get('selectedOrder');
var orderlines = order.get('orderLines').models;
```

But when I print orderlines I get **[object Object]**

Any ideas how I can get the product object of every orderline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a reason why it shows object.

OrderlineCollection definition.

```
module.OrderlineCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: module.Orderline,
});
```

Orderline definition in Order Model.

```
orderLines:     new module.OrderlineCollection()
```

So if you observe above code it shows that orderline is an object of **OrderlineCollection** model and while you get orderlines from order model it will gives you an object of **OrderlineCollection**.

In order to identify what's there inside object you can iterate through it or you may print key-value from that object.

```
alert(orderline.forEach(function(k,v){k + " => + v}));
```

Or you can loop through the orderlines.

```
for (line in orderline){
    alert(line.product_id);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use the `get_orderlines()` function to get OrderLines from particular Order.

```
var order = this.pos.get_order();
var products = _.map(order.get_orderlines(), function (line) {return line.product; });
console.log(products);
```

here i user Underscore.js for create a list of products.

you can iterate loop with products list like,

```
for(var i =0; i < products.length; i++)
    console.log(products[i].id);
```